# Get the total size of selected folders

Tags: mac

I have many files and folders inside a certain folder. I wanna get the total size for the files and/or folders I select select inside this certain folder (because when I click `Get info` I get the size for each one).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Select the folders and press <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> (the letter i)

This will show a "get info" window for the combined items.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

Select folder-> select view (from top near menus)->Select status bar.
Done.
Please see the example screen shots attached here.

[image]